# Nested Fragment onbackpresssed goes to MainActivity instead of back fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I move From Activity to FagmentA then FragmentA to FragmentB. When Press back Button while staying in FragmentB it goes to MainActivity(It should move to a Back fragment which is FragmentA). 
what's wrong with it?

Moving from Activity to FragmentA

```
   Fragment fragment = new FragmentA() ;
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Moving FramgentA to FragmentB

```
 layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            Fragment fragment =new FragmentB ;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Onbackpressed MainActivity

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
        fm.popBackStack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your imports of `FragmentManager` you use both :

`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` and `android.app.FragmentManager`

change this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
        fm.popBackStack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
```

to:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
        fm.popBackStack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed(); 
    }
```

You only add `Fragment`s using the support `FragmentManager` meaning your existing code will always return 0 here -> `fm.getBackStackEntryCount()` until you use correct support `FragmentManager`